# Interface Builder cannot find intrinsicContentSize defined in a custom view

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder

Interface Builder cannot find `intrinsicContentSize` of a custom view.
For this given view code,

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
final class CustomView1: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

I put a `UIView` instance and set its class to `CustomView1`.
It works at first, but if I close and re-open the storyboard, IB **sometimes**(not always) shows an error.

[image]

IB cannot find `width` of the view.

[image]

And this error disappears if I force `Update Frames`.

[image]

It looks like a bug. Or am I missing something important? What's your opinion? Any workaround?

Comment: just curious, is it the same when you set the intrinsic content size in the storyboard? would that solve your problem? also during run time is the intrinsic content size factored in?

Comment: @PrajwalUdupa I didn't and I won't try it because my goal is baking in intrinsic size into a class. If I have to set size for each instance manually, it's way out of intention.

Comment: I understand that... Hence the word curious.. :P But have you tried layout methods in prepare of interface builder? I am not sure if the override will be used before the actual layout... again.. really not sure.. We too are investigating ibdesignable issues.. for us, the view is in a different framework and XCode has issues rendering it in storyboard has throws a lot of errors till it is refreshed in storyboard

Comment: @PrajwalUdupa If code is in different framework, you have to set module name to make IB to locate the code. Anyway, it has numerous errors and bug-like errors in that case, so I would not recommend to put storyboard in other than the main module.

Comment: We have done that... that does not seem to be the issue. it fixes itself and renders correctly after a lot of time.. but coming back to your question,  have you tried layout methods in prepare of interface

Comment: @PrajwalUdupa , obviously (1) you can use the "placeholder" function to just make it show a size in IB - that has nothing to do with the question.  (2) obviously you can add a constraint to make it a height - but that is the exact opposite of using an intrinsic size !

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 11 has intrinsic size option in `Size inspector`. as below

[image]